getting error saying undefined columns selected when running neural networks
    # Split data into train and test sets
    train_ind <- sample(1:nrow(final_e), 0.8 * nrow(final_e))
    train <- final_e[train_ind, ]
    test <- final_e[-train_ind, ]


    # Train neural network model for Brand 2
    #rating_model_e <- rating  ~ model_attr.Female*user_attrMale+ 
model_attr.Female.Male*user_attrFemale + 
    model_attr.Male*user_attrMale


    nn_brand <- neuralnet(
    formula = rating ~ model_attrFemale * user_attrMale + 
                     model_attrFemaleMale * user_attrFemale + 
                     model_attrMale * user_attrMale,
    data = train,
    hidden = c(2), # Example of hidden layer configuration
    linear.output = TRUE,
    err.fct = "sse" # Sum of Squared Error)


I ran that code and I keep getting this error
Error in [.data.frame(data, , model.list$variables) :
undefined columns selected
the columns where generated using dummyVars to get dummy variables. both the formula and the train data have the same columns
